# std::vector<bool> a (b, false); in c#

Tags: c#, c++

Can someone please help me understand what the following code means and how it translates to C#?

```
unsigned int b = 100;
std::vector<bool> a (b, false);
```

if it was something like this:

```
vector<bool> a;
```

I'd probably just go:

```
List<bool> a;
```

Is that correct?

But I don't don't know c++, so I don't understand how a uint and a bool are being passed to a vector of type bool?
Maybe it should be something like this?

```
MyGenericList<int, bool> a = new MyGenericList<int, bool>(b, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20478272/781792) say, the C++ code creates something like an array or list with 100 elements, all `false`.  The equivalent in C# would be:

```
var a = new bool[100];
```

Or if you don't need a fixed size:

```
var a = new List<bool>(100);
// or, if the initial capacity isn't important
var a = new List<bool>();
```

Since the default `bool` value is `false`, you don't need to explicitly specify it anywhere. If you wanted `true` (or, e.g. in a list of `int`s, to default to `-1`), you'd have to loop through it after you created it:

```
var a = new bool[100];
for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    a[i] = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector<bool>` is special, it is implemented as a *bit array* in C++.  In other words, 1 byte stores 8 elements of the vector, the most condense possible way to create an array of bool.  That's available in .NET as well, the exact equivalent declaration is:

```
    int b = 100;
    System.Collections.BitArray a = new System.Collections.BitArray(b);
```

If this array only ever contains 100 elements then, meh, don't bother.  If it is going to contain a million then, yes, do bother.

Comment: Only answer that actually gives a c# equivalent

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<bool> a (b, false);` creates a vector (an array or kind of a C# list) that is 100 bools long and initializes these `bool`s to false.

A note: Do **not** use `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why not to use std::vector<bool>?

Comment: @Jimmy, It works differently than the other types because of space efficiency.

Comment: @Jimmy Because the name vector<bool> doesn't make sense for what it does :)

Comment: @Jimmy: Unlike other types of vector, it doesn't store a contiguous array of `bool` objects, which could cause confusion if you expect it to. For this reason, some zealots issue quasi-religious directives not to use it, even when it is the right tool for the job. More useful advice would be "understand what `vector<bool>` is, and don't use it if you want something else".

Comment: @MikeSeymour I do agree with you but I'd like to add that it's usually simpler for beginners to follow "rules of thumb" rather than having to know about subtle implementation differences of stuff.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: And in my experience, it's usually easier to learn how things work in the first place, than to unlearn "rules of thumb" once I've realised how much they're holding me back. But that's just me.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I sure as hell didn't want to know what monads are and how they work when I was starting Haskell, but that's just me :).

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is the size of vector while second is it's element (see [handly C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)). So

```
std::vector<bool> a(100, false);
```

Create vector of 100 elements, elements of which are `false`.

As pointed out by Scarlet `std::vector<bool>` is 'strange' (it does not have full C++ container interface. I'd not go so far to say 'don't use it' but it's important to know that it might behave strange - the ling above is to 'normal' vector).